# Process for renewing Schengen visa for a new destination

Tags: visas, schengen

I had applied for a Schengen visa with French embassy this March 2015, and had a visa from April-September 2015. Now I want to visit Switzerland in Dec 2015. Should I now apply for a new visa with Swiss embassy or is there an option to extend/renew my old Schengen visa?

Comment: Never heard of a Schengen visa being renewed, most likely you will need a new one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your existing Schengen visa is expired, you must apply for a new one.

Because Switzerland is your "main destination", you must apply to the Swiss authorities.

Quoting the French [embassy](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article384) on the matter:

> Previous grants of visas do no automatically qualify you for a renewal
>   of the same or longer visa. A visa is never renewed or extended, each
>   application is a new application. Your personal situation will be
>   studied by the immigration officer each time you apply and the
>   consular administration will determine if you qualify for a visa.

Comment: @Aks.. consider marking the question as resolved if it was helpful :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding more info, feel free to roll back

Comment: I would add for the OP that although this seems like useless bureaucracy, it is actually beneficial to you to do it this way. Having multiple trips on multiple visas, all approved and completed properly helps build your travel history, and makes future visa requests even more likely to be granted because it shows you understand and follow the rules.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, does this make the question as resolved or do i need to do something else? @blackbird57

Comment: @Aks.. nope, that's it :)